# How can you change images src attributes in mediawiki to access a CDN?

Tags: mediawiki, cdn

We have a mediawiki with lots of images http://bbref.com/bullpen/ and want to serve images via our CDN for obvious reasons, but I can't quite grok how to set things up in mediawiki so that we can get

`img src="/local/path/to/image.png"`

to output as

`img src="http://cdn.example.com/local/path/to/image.png"`

The CDN is up and running, so I don't need any help there.  I just need the fix for mediawiki to change image srcs to point there rather than with a relative link.

thanks,
sean

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following

- [$wgUploadBaseUrl](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgUploadBaseUrl)
- [$wgStylePath](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgStylePath)