# How to load static mediawiki content from a CDN?

Tags: mediawiki, cdn

I'd like to load all the MedaiWiki static resources from a Content Delivery Network (CDN) for obvious reasons (using MW 1.17.0).

I think I need to set $wgStylePath=http://cdn.example.com/ Then put everything currently in my /skins/ directory into http://cdn.example.com/
(this appears to be suggested in this Stack Overflow question/answer: [How can you change images src attributes in mediawiki to access a CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114177/how-can-you-change-images-src-attributes-in-mediawiki-to-access-a-cdn) but it's not very clear

My concern is the .php files that are currently in the /skins/ directory...

My only thought is that I need to put all the sub-directories from /skins/ into the CDN, but not the .php files that are directly in /skins/

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way... is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? (I'd like all the theme related .js, .css and image files to load from the external CDN)

Thanks,

-Dan

Answer (score 1):

There are two completely different paths here: the filesystem path through which the webserver accesses skin-related PHP files ([$wgStyleDirectory](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgStyleDirectory)) and the URL which will be placed in the HTML code and used by the browser to access css/js files ([$wgStylePath](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgStylePath)). If you want to use a CDN, you set the latter to the CDN url and leave the former in peace.

Comment: Thanks. I've moved everything over and set $wgStylePath... I can see the images are coming from the cdn, but js and css files are still being loaded from the original url ie http://example.com/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=startup&only=scripts&skin=vector&* and http://example.com/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared|skins.vector&only=styles&skin=vector&* ... I hoped those files would also load from the CDN. Is there anything more I can set? Thanks again

Comment: To further this, you can see those js and css files on wikipedia.org are being loaded from bits.wikimedia.org - NOT the original en.wikipedia.org domain. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You might try setting [$wgStyleSheetPath](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgStyleSheetPath) or [$wgExtensionAssetsPath](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgExtensionAssetsPath), though those should default to the value of `$wgStylePath`. You can find the configuration file for Wikimedia [here](http://noc.wikimedia.org/conf/highlight.php?file=CommonSettings.php).

Comment: Thanks @Tgr, $wgStyleSheetPath is already set the same as wgStylePath, and setting wgExtensionAssetsPath is more about loading css,js and images for specific plugins. (I don't have plugins that have any of those static resources). I assume Wikimedia is doing this using $wgLoadScript, which is the path to load.php, the resourceLoader, and then all the files it loads (css, js). The problem here is that the url you give for that has to be a full-blown webserver that can execute php, access the database and the php settings file - not really appropriate for a CDN. Any further ideas? thanks.